# Unterschied: "rufen, anrufen, aufrufen, abrufen, zurufen, ausrufen". + Unterschied zw o.g. Wörtern und den Wörtern "schreien"/"nennen beim Namen"?

Tags: meaning, standard-german, difference

ich habe mit dem Problem gestoßen, dass ich immer wieder ins Wörterbuch hineinschauen muss für Bedeutungen von den Wörtern mit Endung "rufen". Ihre Bedeutungen ähneln sich, aber bringen auch irgendwie durcheinander. Nurmalerweise steht im Wörterbuch "eine Äußerung in lauter Stimme machen". Aber da steht da die Frage...sind das Wörter oder Läute?
Die zweite Bedeutung, die Gegeben wird, ist normalerweise "Namen von etwas sagen"...z.B."Stationen ausrufen, den Flug 123 ausrufen, den Herrn Meier aufrufen, jemanden im U-station ausrufen/rufen". Da frage ich mich immer: werden diese Namen gesagt um eine Aufmerksamkeit von jemandem zu bekommen? beim Namen an jemandem wenden? dabei zu sich auffordern/einladen? oder einfach nur den Namen laut sagen?
Das sind die größten zwei Aspekte die immer mich beim Hineinschauen ins Wörterbuch in Verlegenheit bringen....und dabei, da ich die Antwort nicht bekommen kann, versuch ich einfach aus dem Kopf zu schmeissen, und als "laut zu sagen" interpreterien, aber da wozu ganze Menge von Wörtern mit Endung "rufen"?

die Bedeutungen in Wörterbuch, das ich im Wörterbuch ausgelesen habe:

1. das Wort bedeutet mit lauter Stimme etw zu sagen (Wörter).
2. das Wort bedeutet mit lauter Stimme Läute von sich zu geben;
3. das Wort bedeutet j-n bei einem Namen nennen;
4. mit/beim Namen sich an jemanden wenden;
5. beinhaltet "dabei die Aufmerksam von j-n erlangen zu versuchende" Bedeutung;
6. beinhaltet zu sich auffordernde Bedeutung, zu sich einladen;
7. beinhaltet die Bedeutung: "etwas verlangen";
8. Information dabei mitteilende Bedeutung.

*<<<Getrennt, wollte ich das Unterschied zw den Wörtern "rufen, anrufen, aufrufen, abrufen, zurufen, ausrufen" und  "schreien"/ "nennen" wissen.*

lg

Comment: Ich verstehe deinen Post nicht so richtig. Ich habe in meiner "Antwort" die Wörterbucheinträge velrinkt und aus zweien direkt zitiert. Auf welche Probleme bist du genau gestoßen? Die Bedeutungen, die du vorschlägst sind nicht ganz richtig..

Comment: Vielleicht, muss ich den Post irgenwie ändern, und es genau irgendwie beschreiben.

Comment: Ich wollte vielleicht einen kleinen Spickzettel haben, wo alle Wörter zusammen und allein  besprochen werden.....

Comment: Das sind 8*7 = 56 Unterschiede, die man bilden kann. Solche Sammelanfragen überfordern die, die sie beantworten sollen und die, die Antworten dann bewerten sollen.

Comment: D.h., in der Frage geht es darum, ob und wie sich die kursiv aufgeführten Worte in die 8 Bedeutungen einsortieren lassen?

Comment: z.B. "Stationen ausrufen". Bei diesem Satz enthält es eine Information mitteilende Bedeutung oder einfach so etwas laut sagen? Oder "jemanden ausrufen". Ist das Aufmerksam zu bekommen versuchende Bedeutung oder zu sich aufferdernde oder einfach jemandes Namen laut sagen? "jemanden ausrufen" vs "jemanden aufrufen" Unterschied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- mit lauter Stimme etwas sagen (Wörter)

  > **rufen**, **schreien**, **zurufen**, **brüllen**, **ausrufen**, ...
- mit lauter Stimme Laute von sich zu geben

  > (rufen), **schreien**, **aufschreien**, ...
- jmd. bei seinem Namen nennen

  - **nennen**:

  > Du kannst mich gern Basti **nennen**.

  - **gerufen** werden:

  > Er heißt Paul, aber von seinen Eltern wird er „Bubi‟ **gerufen**.
- versuchen die Aufmerksamkeit von jmd. zu erlangen

  > jmd. **rufen**

  > jmd. **aufrufen** (wenn man das in die Kategorie "Aufmerksamkeit erlangen" einordnen möchte)
- zu sich einladen; auffordern zu einer (der eigenen)
  Position zu kommen

  > jmd. **einladen**

  > jmd. **herbeirufen**
- etwas fordern, verlangen

  > im richtigen Moment die bestmögliche Leistung **abrufen** können
- Informationen mitteilen

  > etwas **verkünden**

  > "Am 16.2.2008 wurde im Kosovo die Unabhängigkeit **ausgerufen**."

---

- "[rufen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/rufen)"
- "[ausrufen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/ausrufen)"
- "[anrufen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/anrufen)"
- "[herbeirufen](https://dict.leo.org/german-english/herbeirufen)"
- "[abrufen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/abrufen)"
- "[zurufen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/zurufen)"
- "[aufrufen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/aufrufen)"

---

- "[schreien](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/schreien)"
- "[nennen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/german-english/nennen)":

Comment: Ich dachte ausrufen mehr mit Wörtern zu tun hat und nicht Läuten.... zB im: "Die Stationen ausrufen" es bedeutet ich denke "etw nennen", bin aber nicht sicher... :))))

Comment: „Wahnsinn!‟, rief sie verwundert aus.

Comment: oh..............kapiert

Comment: Kann man ausrufen in die Kategorie "beim Namen nennen" zuordnen? zB Er rief sie im Bahnhofstation aus. Oder geht da besser anrufen?

Comment: @Capuccinolady _Anrufen_ passt in diesem Kontext nicht. Ich finde nicht, dass es in die Kategorie "beim Namen nennen" passt, aber wenn du dir es so merken kannst, warum nicht?

Comment: Nein, ich schätze deine Meinung sehr, ich fühle irgendwie auch dass anrufen da irgendwie missbraucht wird...

Comment: Schreien ist etwas anderes, als etwas mit lauter Stimme zu sagen (usw.).

Comment: @userunknown ich habe versucht mich an die "Bedeutungskategorien" zu halten, die durch OP vorgegeben waren. Ich denke, dass verstanden wurde was gemeint ist, aber du kannst gerne die Antwort editieren, oder selber eine schreiben. :)

Comment: Wer gutwillig ist, und die Bedeutung schon kennt, wird Deine Antwort wohl so lesen können, dass er dem zustimmt - in dem er einfach ausblendet, was nicht passt. Als Antwort für jmd., der nach der Bedeutung fragt, taugt das aber nicht. Ich antworte nicht selbst, sondern habe dafür gestimmt, die Frage zu schließen, weil der Vergleich von 8 Ausdrücken auf 8*7=56 Vergleiche hinausläuft - das ist offenbar keine sinnvolle Strategie, sich den Fragen zu widmen. Die Sprache ist ja nicht arithmetisch, so dass aus einem Vergleich (a, b) und (b, c) schon folgen würde, was der Vergleich (a, c) ergibt.

Comment: @userunknown ja richtig, ich bin da bei dir, ich hab hier den (wahrscheinlich unerwünschten) Weg gewählt und die Frage halbwegs beantwortet nachdem ich das Schließen der Frage vorgeschlagen habe.